# Installed Ubuntu on USB stick and my boot options are scrambled

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, uefi, grub-efi

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my USB drive and everything went smoothly. I did as follows: firstly I formatted the USB drive, started the installation and created a new / partition on it (I'm sure it got installed on the USB) and also selected as the device the boot loader to be installed on the same USB drive (I'm 100% sure of this).

The install finished successfully and I went on to restart, removed both USB drives (the one that had the Ubuntu image on it and the one that I installed Ubuntu on) and to my surprise my laptop booted into GRUB, more accurately it told me that GRUB is missing.

So I plugged the USB drive in my laptop, restarted, and this time it booted into grub (this time it found it on the USB stick) so I accessed the BIOS to see what was going on with my boot options and found this:

[image: boot bios]

`P5: ADATA SP550` is my SSD, on which I have my Windows installed.
I have no idea how this happened. Why my BIOS thinks that GRUB is on my SSD and how to remove that from there and make GRUB be recognized from the USB Ubuntu is installed on.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Edit: I followed the steps in this tutorial trying to get rid of Grub from my SDD MBR: http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/09/05/how-to-delete-grub-files-from-a-boot-efi-partition-in-windows-10/
It didn't completely work, I can still see those boot options. My question is, is `EFI\Boot` still part of Grub? It contains a file named `bootx64.efi`
And is there a way to install Grub on my USB stick MBR?

Answer (score 0):

Grub has its own boot record which can be put to MBR (master boot record) or to the boot record on some partition that is in turn set active, with fdisk, for example.

One possible configuration is to put grub into SSD drive MBR and create grub menu that has 2 positions:

- your Windows
- your Ubuntu on USB stick

Alternatively you can leave SSD MBR intact and put grub to the MBR of the stick with just one option of booting Ubuntu from the stick. Than you can just boot Windows or press F12 and select the stick from BIOS boot menu to boot Ubuntu.

Refer to the grub docs for more details.

Comment: The alternative option would work for me because I want to use this USB stick to boot my Ubuntu on other devices, not just my laptop. So you're saying that my SSD MBR is untouched by the Ubuntu installation?

Comment: I can boot into my Windows, If I select Windows Boot Manager as my top boot priority. What I want to do is remove Grub from my SSD MBR (if it somehow got there) and place it on my Ubuntu USB drive.

Comment: What you need is some Linux Live USB with grub and Windows CD. 

First reset Windows boot config by booting from Windows CD and make Windows boot correctly. When you boot from Windows CD there is an option to reset boot cfg.

Than you need to boot from Linux Live USB stick and carefully craft grub cfg to put it on MBR of the target USB stick.

What I usually do on such occasions is to detach Windows SSD/HDD from the computer to be sure not to spoil it.

Comment: Are you referring to the "Startup Repair" option in Windows? http://static.myce.com/images_posts/2015/12/myce-command-prompt-windows-10.png

Comment: Most probably - I am still with Windows 7. Be sure to use "fix MBR" option if it is available.

Comment: `fixmbr` will not help here, this looks like an UEFI-install and Grub is installed in the ESP (EFI System Partition) of the first drive(sda) by default whatever you choose during installation.

Comment: Yup, can confirm that `fixmbr` did not work. Any other solution?

Comment: Now the question is how to fix UEFI boot. I can vaguely remember that there was some option to recreate Windows UEFI cfg that I used once, some time ago. What I currently use is Windows UEFI boot and F12 and legacy mode to boot from the stick. Works nice.

Comment: I have done some research and found a Windows software called `Easyuefi` that gives you the option to delete `EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi` and `EFI\Ubuntu\grubx64.efi` but I'm not sure how safe that is and if it will remove the whole Grub from my MBR. Also, still have no idea to place Grub on my USB stick's MBR.

Comment: There are several sources of grub docs that may help. For example: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/grub-documentation.html or https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2 . Also once you have your Windows config fixed you can ask separate about configuring grub on the stick.

Comment: So a command like `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX` where `X` would be the drive letter of the USB stick should work? Also, this could work to fix my Windows MBR, do you think it's safe? http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/09/05/how-to-delete-grub-files-from-a-boot-efi-partition-in-windows-10/

Comment: I did the steps listed there, it didn't work, even though I can confirm I deleted `EFI\ubuntu` folder. Edited the post...

Comment: As far as i k... UEFI supports GPT disk.. and u r talking about MBR...UEFI is supposed to use use GPT table... even though if there is MBR table..UEFI boot mode doesn't use bootstrap code in MBR table